# How to expand and show the full length of a label inside a collection view cell when tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uilabel

There are a grid of cells in collectionView, if the label text inside a cell is too long to display i’ve truncated the tail. Now when the user long taps / holds the cell the full length text appears like a UIMenu option. But if the text is too long it is again truncated and shown in the UIContextMenu also. How to fix this?
I've added the code snippet for the context menu display in the collectionView cell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
    
    if collectionView == headerCollectionView {
        let headerText = headers[indexPath.row].label
        return configureContextMenu(text: headerText)
    }
    
    else if collectionView == collectionView {
        var data: [String] = []
        dataOrganiser.getDataForSection(section: sections[indexPath.section], dataArray: &data)
        return configureContextMenu(text: data[indexPath.item])
    }
    return configureContextMenu(text: "")
}


func configureContextMenu(text: String) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration {
    
    let context = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { (action) -> UIMenu? in
        
        let edit = UIAction(title: text, identifier: nil, discoverabilityTitle: nil, state: .off) { _ in }
        
        return UIMenu(title: "", image: nil, identifier: nil, options: UIMenu.Options.destructive, children: [edit])
    }
    return context
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I need more information to answer your question. Probably some code as well.

But assuming the long press gesture is added to the cell, you probably want to call a function that changes the `numberOfLines` property on the cell. Assuming you're using `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>`, you need to update `item` (there should be some communication between your cell and the `item`), so that the datasource sees the `item`, which is hashable, has changed. Then, it displays the changes.

Some people take another approach where they just create two cells in which one shows only one line and the other one sets `numberOfLines` to zero. Then, the view controller (if you're following MVC, or the view model if you're following MVVM), switches between the two cells.